# Why is the pyqtSignal() a class attribute, while it actually behaves as an instance attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, signals-slots

After reading the post https://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide I think I grasp the difference between `class attributes` and `instance attributes`. But there is still a weird phenomenon that I cannot explain: the behaviour of the `pyqtSignal()` in PyQt.

## 1. About class attributes

I've learned that class attributes exist in the namespace of the class. If you access such variable - for example `class_var` - through an instance, Python will first look in the namespace of the instance. Not finding it there, Python looks at the namespace of the class.

#### 1.1 Primitive class attributes

Let's look at a class attribute which is a simple integer. You should access it through the class itself, but you can also do it through one of its instances:

```py
class MyClass(object):
    class_var = 1

    def __init__(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj_01 = MyClass()
    obj_02 = MyClass()

    # Access the 'class_var' attribute
    print("obj_01.class_var  -> " + str(obj_01.class_var))   # prints 1
    print("obj_02.class_var  -> " + str(obj_02.class_var))   # prints 1
    print("MyClass.class_var -> " + str(MyClass.class_var))  # prints 1
```

However, if you assign a new value to `class_var` through an instance, you actually create a *new* attribute named `class_var` in the namespace of that particular instance. The actual class variable remains untouched:

```py
    obj_01.class_var = 3
    print("obj_01.class_var  -> " + str(obj_01.class_var))   # prints 3
    print("obj_02.class_var  -> " + str(obj_02.class_var))   # prints 1
    print("MyClass.class_var -> " + str(MyClass.class_var))  # prints 1
```

The following figure illustrates what happens:

[image]

#### 1.2 Mutable class attributes <sub>(non-primitive)</sub>

In the previous example, the assignment `obj_01.class_var = 3` didn't touch the actual class variable - it just created an new instance variable for the particular object.
The story gets more complicated for mutable (non-primitive) class attributes. Consider this:

```py
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def get_str_value(self):
        myStr = "(" + str(self.a) + "," + str(self.b) + ")"
        return myStr

class MyClass(object):
    class_var = Foo(1, 1)

    def __init__(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj_01 = MyClass()
    obj_02 = MyClass()

    # Access the 'class_var' attribute
    print("obj_01.class_var  -> " + obj_01.class_var.get_str_value())   # prints (1,1)
    print("obj_02.class_var  -> " + obj_02.class_var.get_str_value())   # prints (1,1)
    print("MyClass.class_var -> " + MyClass.class_var.get_str_value())  # prints (1,1)

    # Change it
    obj_01.class_var.a = 3
    print("obj_01.class_var  -> " + obj_01.class_var.get_str_value())   # prints (3,1)
    print("obj_02.class_var  -> " + obj_02.class_var.get_str_value())   # prints (3,1)
    print("MyClass.class_var -> " + MyClass.class_var.get_str_value())  # prints (3,1)
```

I don't reassign a new `Foo()`-object to the variable, I merely mutate it. I do the mutation through instance `obj_01`, but the mutation happens on the actual class variable, wich is common to all instances of that class:
[image]

## 2. The weird behaviour of pyqtSignal()

Consider the following code sample. Class `EmitterTester` has one class attribute named `signal`.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class EmitterTester(QObject):
    signal = pyqtSignal()   # class attribute 'signal'
    def __init__(self):
        super(EmitterTester, self).__init__()
        pass

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Just create a window with a "START TEST" button.
        '''
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("Emitter tester")

        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.frame.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)

        self.button = QPushButton()
        self.button.setText("START TEST")
        self.button.setFixedHeight(50)
        self.button.setFixedWidth(100)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start_test)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.show()

    def start_test(self):
        '''
        This is the actual test code!
        '''
        obj_01 = EmitterTester()
        obj_02 = EmitterTester()
        obj_01.signal.connect(lambda: print("one"))
        obj_02.signal.connect(lambda: print("two"))

        obj_01.signal.emit()            # prints "one"
        obj_02.signal.emit()            # prints "two"
        EmitterTester.signal.emit()     # throws error

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myGUI = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So let us look at the problematic code snippet step-by-step.

**STEP 1**
First we create two instances of the `EmitterTest` class. The class variable named `signal` is not yet connected to anything.

```py
obj_01 = EmitterTester()
obj_02 = EmitterTester()
```

[image]

**STEP 2**
Next, we connect the `signal` class variable to a lambda function that prints "one". We access the `signal` class variable through `obj_01`, but that shouldn't matter, because we're not assigning a new value but merely mutating it:

```py
obj_01.signal.connect(lambda: print("one"))
```

[image]

**STEP 3**
At last, we connect the `signal` class variable to a lambda function that prints "two". This time we access the `signal` class variable through `obj_02`, but again, that shouldn't matter:

```py
obj_02.signal.connect(lambda: print("one"))
```

[image]

**STEP 4**
Finally we call the `emit()` method on `signal`. First we reach `signal` through `obj_01`, next through `obj_02`. The *`emit()` method behaves differently, depending on how we reach the `signal` attribute!*

```py
obj_01.signal.emit()            # prints "one"
obj_02.signal.emit()            # prints "two"
```

[image]

## 3. My questions

My first question to you is: why does the `emit()` method behave differently, depending on how we reach the `signal` attribute?

One possible explanation could be that `obj_01` and `obj_02` each made their own copy of the class variable (so they actually created each their own "instance variable"). To verify this theory, I checked the namespaces of the objects and the class:

```py
print(obj_01.__dict__)         # prints "{}"
print(obj_02.__dict__)         # prints "{}"
print(EmitterTester.__dict__)  # prints "{'__module__' : '__main__',
                               #              'signal' : <unbound PYQT_SIGNAL signal()>,
                               #            '__init__' : <function EmitterTester.__init__ at 0x000001DE592098C8>,
                               #             '__doc__' : None}
```

As you can see, the `signal` attribute is only in the namespace of the class. The objects don't have their own copy.

My second question to you is: why does `EmitterTester.signal.emit()` throw an error? I'm merely accessing the class variable as it should happen...